# My recycle bin is empty, but my $RECYCLE.BIN folders are not. Why?

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

I have 2 drives on my windows 7 machine. C and D. C is my main drive with the OS, D is a media drive where all my downloads and rips go.

My recycle bin is empty, but right now the `C:\$RECYCLE.BIN` is 2.5G and the `D:\$RECYCLE.BIN` is 6.8G! What exactly are these folders? I figured it's where recycled files live, but if my bin is empty, why aren't these?

Comment: Did you try opening them and looking at what’s inside? (I usually find that level of residual deleted files after using Windows Update.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be that those are recycled files from another users. Windows 7 stores each's user recycle bin as a subdirectory.

Do notice that, if you did reinstall without formatting drive, you might have "orphaned" user in recycle bin from your previous installation.

Comment: Looks like it was the other user, at least for the `C` drive. What's weird is the `D` drive's recycle bin folder didn't change at all. I just deleted it manually.